# Making a pause menu

Tags: python, variables, pause

I am making a python snake game and am trying to make a pause/unpause function. I made it so if I click "q" it sets the game into pause, and "e" unpause (just for now, I will change these later. I'm just working on getting it to work right now.) Here is the code for the pause/unpause:

```
    def setstop():
        head.direction = "Stop"
        dontkill = "1"
        undopause = "0"
        pen.goto(0, 0)
        pen.write("Paused".format (
                  score), align="center", font=("times", 35, "bold italic"))
        if undopause == "1":
                pen.color(0,0,0,0)
                pen.write("Paused".format (
                          score), align="center", font=("times", 35, "bold italic"))
        
def unpause():
        head.direction = secondheaddirection
        undopause = "1"
        dontkill = "0"
```

Once "q" is detected, it sets the head direction to "stop" and dontkill to "1". This is fine. The head direction gets set to "stop". What I don't know is my dontkill. My code originally (before trying the pause menu) just said if the head position is less then 20 pixels away from the body, it would reset the game. I made it now say this:

```
) 
        if len(segments) > 0:
                if dontkill == "0":
                        x = head.xcor() 
                        y = head.ycor() 
                        segments[0].goto(x, y)
                if dontkill == "1":
                        freeze.segment.position

        move() 
        for segment in segments:
                if segment.distance(head) < 20:
                        if dontkill == "0":
                                time.sleep(.5) 
                                head.goto(0, 0) 
                                head.direction = "Stop"
                                colors = random.choice(['red', 'blue',]) 
                                shapes = random.choice(['square', 'circle']) 
                                for segment in segments: 
                                        segment.goto(1000, 1000) 
                                segments.clear() 
                                score = 0
                                delay = 0.1
                                if delay_score > high_score:
                                        high_score = delay_score
                                pen.clear()
                                pen.goto(175, -350)
                                pen.color("white")
                                pen.write("Score : {} ".format( 
                                        score), align="center", font=("times", 24, "bold"))
                                pen.goto(0, 300)
                                pen.color("red")
                                pen.write("You Died" .format(
                                        high_score), align="center", font=("times", 30, "bold"))
                        if dontkill == "1":
                                freeze.segment.position
```

So if dontkill is off, the segments will try to goto the head. If it is on, the segments freeze. All that works.
Then, if dontkill is off, and the segment.position is <20 pixels from the head position, it dies. if dontkill is on, the segments freeze. But when I pause it, everything freezes as it should, but then the game restarts and the "you died" text pops up. So for some reason, the game thinks that I should still die, even though "dontkill" is on.

Another issue I have with this code is that after I pause, if I unpause it won't keep moving in the direction it was. I have to repress wasd to keep moving after paused. (I tested this without getting any segments so I wont die. Also, the "Paused" text doesn't disappear until I eat the next apple. To try to fix this, I made a "secondheaddirection" variable. When I go up, down, left, or right, it also sets this variable to up, down, left, or right. You can see in the first block of code that I added that it should set the head.direction to the secondheaddirection. This should mean that it goes to the most recent direction that isn't "stop". It doesn't do that though. Below is my full code, it's kind of a mess because of all the random stuff that I have tried but if you guys can help, I'm open to ideas! Thanks!

```
# import modules
import turtle 
import time 
import random 

# set variables  
delay = 0.1
score = 0
high_score = 0
delay_score = 0
keep_moving = "Stop"
set_stop = "off"
stopon = "on"
stopoff = "off"
undopause = "1"
secondheaddirection = "abc"
dontkill = "0"



# Creating a window screen 
wn = turtle.Screen() 
wn.title("Luke's Snake Game") 
wn.bgcolor("black")

# the size of window 
wn.setup(width=630, height=700) 
wn.tracer(0) 

# head of the snake 
head = turtle.Turtle() 
head.shape("square") 
head.color("green") 
head.penup() 
head.goto(0, 0) 
head.direction = "Stop"


# food in the game 
food = turtle.Turtle() 
colors = random.choice(['red',]) 
shapes = random.choice(['square',]) 
food.speed(0) 
food.shape(shapes) 
food.color(colors) 
food.penup() 
food.goto(0, 100) 


pen = turtle.Turtle() 
pen.speed(0) 
pen.shape("square") 
pen.color("white") 
pen.penup() 
pen.hideturtle() 
pen.goto(175, -350) 
pen.write("Score : {} ".format (
        score), align="center", font=("times", 24, "bold"))


# assigning key directions 
def goup(): 
        if head.direction != "down": 
                head.direction = "up"


def godown(): 
        if head.direction != "up": 
                head.direction = "down"
        

def goleft(): 
        if head.direction != "right": 
                head.direction = "left"


def goright(): 
        if head.direction != "left": 
                head.direction = "right"

def setstop():
        head.direction = "Stop"
        dontkill = "1"
        undopause = "0"
        pen.goto(0, 0)
        pen.write("Paused".format (
                  score), align="center", font=("times", 35, "bold italic"))
        if undopause == "1":
                pen.color(0,0,0,0)
                pen.write("Paused".format (
                          score), align="center", font=("times", 35, "bold italic"))
        
def unpause():
        head.direction = secondheaddirection
        undopause = "1"
        dontkill = "0"

# keeps moving
def move():
        if head.direction == "up": 
                y = head.ycor() 
                head.sety(y+20)
                secondheaddirection = "up"
        if head.direction == "down": 
                y = head.ycor() 
                head.sety(y-20)
                secondheaddirection = "down"
        if head.direction == "left": 
                x = head.xcor() 
                head.setx(x-20)
                secondheaddirection = "left"
        if head.direction == "right": 
                x = head.xcor() 
                head.setx(x+20)
                secondheaddirection = "right"

# checks and moves based on key pressed
wn.listen() 
wn.onkeypress(goup, "w") 
wn.onkeypress(godown, "s") 
wn.onkeypress(goleft, "a") 
wn.onkeypress(goright, "d")
wn.onkeypress(setstop, "q")
wn.onkeypress(unpause, "e")

segments = [] 

# Main Gameplay 
while True: 
        wn.update()
        if head.direction != "Stop":
                pen.goto(0, 300)
                pen.color("black")
                pen.write("You Died" .format(
                        high_score), align="center", font=("times", 30, "bold"))
                keep_moving = head.direction
        if head.xcor() > 290 or head.xcor() < -290 or head.ycor() > 290 or head.ycor() < -290: 
                time.sleep(1) 
                head.goto(0, 0) 
                head.direction = "Stop"
                colors = random.choice(['red', 'blue',]) 
                shapes = random.choice(['square', 'circle']) 
                for segment in segments: 
                        segment.goto(1000, 1000) 
                segments.clear() 
                score = 0
                delay = 0.1
                if delay_score > high_score:
                        high_score = delay_score
                pen.clear()
                pen.goto(175, -350)
                pen.color("white")
                pen.write("Score : {} ".format( 
                        score), align="center", font=("times", 24, "bold"))

                pen.goto(0, 300)
                pen.color("red")
                pen.write("You Died" .format(
                        high_score), align="center", font=("times", 30, "bold"))
        if head.distance(food) < 20: 
                x = random.randint(-27, 27) 
                y = random.randint(-27, 27) 
                food.goto(x * 10, y * 10)


                # Adding segment 
                new_segment = turtle.Turtle() 
                new_segment.speed(0) 
                new_segment.shape("square") 
                new_segment.color("green") # tail colour 
                new_segment.penup() 
                segments.append(new_segment) 
                delay -= 0.001
                score += 1
                if score > delay_score: 
                        delay_score = score
                pen.clear()
                pen.goto(175, -350)
                pen.color("white")
                pen.write("Score : {} ".format( 
                        score), align="center", font=("times", 24, "bold")) 
        # Checking for head collisions with body segments 
        for index in range(len(segments)-1, 0, -1): 
                x = segments[index-1].xcor() 
                y = segments[index-1].ycor() 
                segments[index].goto(x, y) 
        if len(segments) > 0:
                if dontkill == "0":
                        x = head.xcor() 
                        y = head.ycor() 
                        segments[0].goto(x, y)
                if dontkill == "1":
                        freeze.segment.position

        move() 
        for segment in segments:
                if segment.distance(head) < 20:
                        if dontkill == "0":
                                time.sleep(.5) 
                                head.goto(0, 0) 
                                head.direction = "Stop"
                                colors = random.choice(['red', 'blue',]) 
                                shapes = random.choice(['square', 'circle']) 
                                for segment in segments: 
                                        segment.goto(1000, 1000) 
                                segments.clear() 
                                score = 0
                                delay = 0.1
                                if delay_score > high_score:
                                        high_score = delay_score
                                pen.clear()
                                pen.goto(175, -350)
                                pen.color("white")
                                pen.write("Score : {} ".format( 
                                        score), align="center", font=("times", 24, "bold"))
                                pen.goto(0, 300)
                                pen.color("red")
                                pen.write("You Died" .format(
                                        high_score), align="center", font=("times", 30, "bold"))
                        if dontkill == "1":
                                freeze.segment.position

        pen.goto(-175, -350)
        pen.color("white")
        pen.write("High score : {}" .format(
                        high_score), align="center", font=("times", 24, "bold"))
        time.sleep(delay) 

wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to edit global variables in a python function (although the use of global variables is often frowned upon), as you wish to do in your `setstop`and `unpause` functions, you must specify that with the `global` keyword:

```
def setstop():
        global dontkill, undopause
        head.direction = "Stop"
        dontkill = "1"
        undopause = "0"
        pen.goto(0, 0)
        pen.write("Paused".format (
                  score), align="center", font=("times", 35, "bold italic"))
        if undopause == "1":
                pen.color(0,0,0,0)
                pen.write("Paused".format (
                          score), align="center", font=("times", 35, "bold italic"))
        
def unpause():
        global undopause, dontkill
        head.direction = secondheaddirection
        undopause = "1"
        dontkill = "0"
```

This results in what I'm guessing is your expected behaviour as the lines with `freeze.segment.position` are reached, although I'm not sure what you mean by that as `freeze`is not defined.

Comment: Thanks! I no longer die when I pause. I still am not able to unpause though. The "paused" text doesn't disappear and I don't keep moving. How would I fix that?